# Forgot password Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Good Afternoon every one,
I know this is very old question but I am very new to programming.Could any one help me 
I have a forgot password page and it contains 
 Save button type is submit,Go to login link and one "User Name" of type input text.

Now when I click on save it should execute the following code

```
enter code here public VWUser ResetPassword(string userName)
    {
        using (var db = new AppDB())
        {
            var data = db.VWUsers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.UserName == userName && m.TenantId==Helper.TenantId);
            if (data == null)
                throw Helper.AppException(ExceptionTypes.Data, LocalText.ERR_UnAuthorizedAccess);
            var password = SecurityManager.GenerateRandomPassword();
            //data.Password = SecurityManager.Hash(password);
            data.Password = SecurityManager.EncryptData(password);
            db.SaveAndAssertChanges();
            var result = db.VWUsers.First(x => x.UserName == data.UserName && x.TenantId ==Helper.TenantId);
            result.xPassword = password;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And my Js will be like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
   $("#frm-data").validate({
        rules: {
            UserName: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 50,
            },

        },
        showErrors: Helper.validateForm,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            debugger;
            Helper.httpPost("~/Login/ForgotPass",form, function (result) {
                if (result.Status == 1) {
                  Helper.redirect("Login/Index");
                }
                else {
                    Helper.warning("Invalid Username or Password.");
                   // Helper.warning(result.Data);
                }
            })
        }
    });
})
```

can any one let me know how to do this.

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Are you getting errors ?

Comment: no when i click on save button the page remains same it didn't goes to the resetpassword() function.My problem is when i click on the save button it should go to resetpassword() function and execute it.

Comment: Well then its the issue with your routing. Your router code should call the function `ResetPassword()` when the  `~/Login/ForgotPass` route is hit.